# Does anyone know a way I can use a loop to replace the parts of the code where everything is identical except for the index?

Tags: javascript, function, loops, binding, scope

The current code will convert a csv file into a graph. My entire html file is made up of the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
<title> Test Graph </title>
<style> /* set the CSS */

svg { font: 12px Arial;}

path { 
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2.5;
  fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

div.tooltip {   
  position: absolute;           
  text-align: center;           
  width: 120px;                  
  height: 28px;                 
  padding: 2px;             
  font: 12px sans-serif;        
  background: lightsteelblue;   
  border: 0px;      
  border-radius: 8px;           
  pointer-events: none;         
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2 align="center"> Test Graph </h2>
<data src = "data.csv"></data>

<!-- load the d3.js library --> 
<!-- Also on http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>

// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%x").parse;
var formatTime = d3.time.format("%B %e, %Y");

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(3);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(25);

var dataBase = [
    {
        valueline:"", 
        columnline:"First",
        dataVar:"",
        dataName:"First",
        colorcode:"#FF0000"
    },
    {
        valueline:"", 
        columnline:"Second",
        dataVar:"",
        dataName:"Second",
        colorcode:"#FF8000"
    },
    {
        valueline:"", 
        columnline:"Third",
        dataVar:"",
        dataName:"Third",
        colorcode:"#FFFF00"
    },
    {
        valueline:"", 
        columnline:"Fourth",
        dataVar:"",
        dataName:"Fourth",
        colorcode:"#00FF00"
    },
    {
        valueline:"", 
        columnline:"Fifth",
        dataVar:"",
        dataName:"Fifth",
        colorcode:"#00FFFF"
    },
    {
        valueline:"", 
        columnline:"Sixth",
        dataVar:"",
        dataName:"Sixth",
        colorcode:"#0080FF"
    },
    {
        valueline:"", 
        columnline:"Seventh",
        dataVar:"",
        dataName:"Seventh",
        colorcode:"#0000FF"
    },
    {
        valueline:"", 
        columnline:"Eighth",
        dataVar:"",
        dataName:"Eighth",
        colorcode:"#FF00FF"
    },
    {
        valueline:"", 
        columnline:"Ninth",
        dataVar:"",
        dataName:"Ninth",
        colorcode:"#000000"
    }

];


// Define the line
dataBase[0].valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d["Date"]); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d[dataBase[0].columnline]); });

dataBase[1].valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d["Date"]); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d[dataBase[1].columnline]); });

dataBase[2].valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d["Date"]); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d[dataBase[2].columnline]); });

dataBase[3].valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d["Date"]); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d[dataBase[3].columnline]); });

dataBase[4].valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d["Date"]); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d[dataBase[4].columnline]); });

dataBase[5].valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d["Date"]); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d[dataBase[5].columnline]); });

dataBase[6].valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d["Date"]); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d[dataBase[6].columnline]); });

dataBase[7].valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d["Date"]); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d[dataBase[7].columnline]); });

dataBase[8].valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d["Date"]); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d[dataBase[8].columnline]); });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right + 170)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
    .attr("class", "tooltip")               
    .style("opacity", 0);

var singleData = false;

// Get the data
drawGraph = function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d["Date"] = parseDate(d["Date"]);
        for (i = 0; i < dataBase.length; i++) {
            d[dataBase[i].columnline] = 
                +d[dataBase[i].columnline];
        }
    });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d["Date"]; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
        var maxim = d[dataBase[0].columnline];
        for (var i = 1; i < dataBase.length; i++) {
            if (d[dataBase[i].columnline] > maxim) {
                maxim = d[dataBase[i].columnline];
            }
        }
        return maxim; 
    })]);

    var dataVars = ["","","","","","","",""];


    dataBase[0].dataVar = svg.append("g")
        .attr("id", ("data " + (1 + 0)));

    // Add the valueline path.
    dataBase[0].dataVar.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .style("stroke", dataBase[0].colorcode)
        .attr("d", dataBase[0].valueline(data));

    dataBase[0].dataVar.selectAll("dot")    
        .data(data)         
    .enter().append("circle")                           
        .attr("r", 4.0)      
        .style("fill", dataBase[0].colorcode)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d["Date"]); })       
        .attr("cy", function(d) { 
            return y(d[dataBase[0].columnline]); 
        })     
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
            div.transition()        
                .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .9);      
            div .html(formatTime(d["Date"]) + "<br/>" + 
            "Quantity: " + d[dataBase[0].columnline])  
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
            })                  
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
            div.transition()        
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0);   
        });

    dataBase[0].dataVar.append("rect")
        .attr("x", width + 150)
        .attr("y", 25 * 0)
        .attr("width", 18)
        .attr("height", 18)
        .style("fill", dataBase[0].colorcode)
        .on("click", function(d) {
            if (singleData) {
                singleData = false;
                svg.selectAll("g").remove();
                d3.csv("data.csv", drawGraph);
            }
            else {
                singleData = true;
                for (j = 0; j < dataBase.length; j++) {
                    if (j != 0) {
                        dataBase[j].dataVar.remove();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    dataBase[0].dataVar.append("text")
        .attr("x", width + 145)
        .attr("y", 9 + 25 * 0)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text(dataBase[0].dataName);



    dataBase[1].dataVar = svg.append("g")
        .attr("id", ("data " + (1 + 1)));

    // Add the valueline path.
    dataBase[1].dataVar.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .style("stroke", dataBase[1].colorcode)
        .attr("d", dataBase[1].valueline(data));

    dataBase[1].dataVar.selectAll("dot")    
        .data(data)         
    .enter().append("circle")                           
        .attr("r", 4.0)      
        .style("fill", dataBase[1].colorcode)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d["Date"]); })       
        .attr("cy", function(d) { 
            return y(d[dataBase[1].columnline]); 
        })     
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
            div.transition()        
                .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .9);      
            div .html(formatTime(d["Date"]) + "<br/>" + 
            "Quantity: " + d[dataBase[1].columnline])  
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
            })                  
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
            div.transition()        
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0);   
        });

    dataBase[1].dataVar.append("rect")
        .attr("x", width + 150)
        .attr("y", 25 * 1)
        .attr("width", 18)
        .attr("height", 18)
        .style("fill", dataBase[1].colorcode)
        .on("click", function(d) {
            if (singleData) {
                singleData = false;
                svg.selectAll("g").remove();
                d3.csv("data.csv", drawGraph);
            }
            else {
                singleData = true;
                for (j = 0; j < dataBase.length; j++) {
                    if (j != 1) {
                        dataBase[j].dataVar.remove();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    dataBase[1].dataVar.append("text")
        .attr("x", width + 145)
        .attr("y", 9 + 25 * 1)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text(dataBase[1].dataName);



    dataBase[2].dataVar = svg.append("g")
        .attr("id", ("data " + (1 + 2)));

    // Add the valueline path.
    dataBase[2].dataVar.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .style("stroke", dataBase[2].colorcode)
        .attr("d", dataBase[2].valueline(data));

    dataBase[2].dataVar.selectAll("dot")    
        .data(data)         
    .enter().append("circle")                           
        .attr("r", 4.0)      
        .style("fill", dataBase[2].colorcode)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d["Date"]); })       
        .attr("cy", function(d) { 
            return y(d[dataBase[2].columnline]); 
        })     
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
            div.transition()        
                .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .9);      
            div .html(formatTime(d["Date"]) + "<br/>" + 
            "Quantity: " + d[dataBase[2].columnline])  
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
            })                  
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
            div.transition()        
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0);   
        });

    dataBase[2].dataVar.append("rect")
        .attr("x", width + 150)
        .attr("y", 25 * 2)
        .attr("width", 18)
        .attr("height", 18)
        .style("fill", dataBase[2].colorcode)
        .on("click", function(d) {
            if (singleData) {
                singleData = false;
                svg.selectAll("g").remove();
                d3.csv("data.csv", drawGraph);
            }
            else {
                singleData = true;
                for (j = 0; j < dataBase.length; j++) {
                    if (j != 2) {
                        dataBase[j].dataVar.remove();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    dataBase[2].dataVar.append("text")
        .attr("x", width + 145)
        .attr("y", 9 + 25 * 2)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text(dataBase[2].dataName);



    dataBase[3].dataVar = svg.append("g")
        .attr("id", ("data " + (1 + 3)));

    // Add the valueline path.
    dataBase[3].dataVar.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .style("stroke", dataBase[3].colorcode)
        .attr("d", dataBase[3].valueline(data));

    dataBase[3].dataVar.selectAll("dot")    
        .data(data)         
    .enter().append("circle")                           
        .attr("r", 4.0)      
        .style("fill", dataBase[3].colorcode)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d["Date"]); })       
        .attr("cy", function(d) { 
            return y(d[dataBase[3].columnline]); 
        })     
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
            div.transition()        
                .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .9);      
            div .html(formatTime(d["Date"]) + "<br/>" + 
            "Quantity: " + d[dataBase[3].columnline])  
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
            })                  
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
            div.transition()        
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0);   
        });

    dataBase[3].dataVar.append("rect")
        .attr("x", width + 150)
        .attr("y", 25 * 3)
        .attr("width", 18)
        .attr("height", 18)
        .style("fill", dataBase[3].colorcode)
        .on("click", function(d) {
            if (singleData) {
                singleData = false;
                svg.selectAll("g").remove();
                d3.csv("data.csv", drawGraph);
            }
            else {
                singleData = true;
                for (j = 0; j < dataBase.length; j++) {
                    if (j != 3) {
                        dataBase[j].dataVar.remove();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    dataBase[3].dataVar.append("text")
        .attr("x", width + 145)
        .attr("y", 9 + 25 * 3)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text(dataBase[3].dataName);



    dataBase[4].dataVar = svg.append("g")
        .attr("id", ("data " + (1 + 4)));

    // Add the valueline path.
    dataBase[4].dataVar.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .style("stroke", dataBase[4].colorcode)
        .attr("d", dataBase[4].valueline(data));

    dataBase[4].dataVar.selectAll("dot")    
        .data(data)         
    .enter().append("circle")                           
        .attr("r", 4.0)      
        .style("fill", dataBase[4].colorcode)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d["Date"]); })       
        .attr("cy", function(d) { 
            return y(d[dataBase[4].columnline]); 
        })     
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
            div.transition()        
                .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .9);      
            div .html(formatTime(d["Date"]) + "<br/>" + 
            "Quantity: " + d[dataBase[4].columnline])  
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
            })                  
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
            div.transition()        
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0);   
        });

    dataBase[4].dataVar.append("rect")
        .attr("x", width + 150)
        .attr("y", 25 * 4)
        .attr("width", 18)
        .attr("height", 18)
        .style("fill", dataBase[4].colorcode)
        .on("click", function(d) {
            if (singleData) {
                singleData = false;
                svg.selectAll("g").remove();
                d3.csv("data.csv", drawGraph);
            }
            else {
                singleData = true;
                for (j = 0; j < dataBase.length; j++) {
                    if (j != 4) {
                        dataBase[j].dataVar.remove();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    dataBase[4].dataVar.append("text")
        .attr("x", width + 145)
        .attr("y", 9 + 25 * 4)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text(dataBase[4].dataName);



    dataBase[5].dataVar = svg.append("g")
        .attr("id", ("data " + (1 + 5)));

    // Add the valueline path.
    dataBase[5].dataVar.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .style("stroke", dataBase[5].colorcode)
        .attr("d", dataBase[5].valueline(data));

    dataBase[5].dataVar.selectAll("dot")    
        .data(data)         
    .enter().append("circle")                           
        .attr("r", 4.0)      
        .style("fill", dataBase[5].colorcode)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d["Date"]); })       
        .attr("cy", function(d) { 
            return y(d[dataBase[5].columnline]); 
        })     
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
            div.transition()        
                .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .9);      
            div .html(formatTime(d["Date"]) + "<br/>" + 
            "Quantity: " + d[dataBase[5].columnline])  
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
            })                  
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
            div.transition()        
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0);   
        });

    dataBase[5].dataVar.append("rect")
        .attr("x", width + 150)
        .attr("y", 25 * 5)
        .attr("width", 18)
        .attr("height", 18)
        .style("fill", dataBase[5].colorcode)
        .on("click", function(d) {
            if (singleData) {
                singleData = false;
                svg.selectAll("g").remove();
                d3.csv("data.csv", drawGraph);
            }
            else {
                singleData = true;
                for (j = 0; j < dataBase.length; j++) {
                    if (j != 5) {
                        dataBase[j].dataVar.remove();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    dataBase[5].dataVar.append("text")
        .attr("x", width + 145)
        .attr("y", 9 + 25 * 5)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text(dataBase[5].dataName);



    dataBase[6].dataVar = svg.append("g")
        .attr("id", ("data " + (1 + 6)));

    // Add the valueline path.
    dataBase[6].dataVar.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .style("stroke", dataBase[6].colorcode)
        .attr("d", dataBase[6].valueline(data));

    dataBase[6].dataVar.selectAll("dot")    
        .data(data)         
    .enter().append("circle")                           
        .attr("r", 4.0)      
        .style("fill", dataBase[6].colorcode)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d["Date"]); })       
        .attr("cy", function(d) { 
            return y(d[dataBase[6].columnline]); 
        })     
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
            div.transition()        
                .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .9);      
            div .html(formatTime(d["Date"]) + "<br/>" + 
            "Quantity: " + d[dataBase[6].columnline])  
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
            })                  
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
            div.transition()        
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0);   
        });

    dataBase[6].dataVar.append("rect")
        .attr("x", width + 150)
        .attr("y", 25 * 6)
        .attr("width", 18)
        .attr("height", 18)
        .style("fill", dataBase[6].colorcode)
        .on("click", function(d) {
            if (singleData) {
                singleData = false;
                svg.selectAll("g").remove();
                d3.csv("data.csv", drawGraph);
            }
            else {
                singleData = true;
                for (j = 0; j < dataBase.length; j++) {
                    if (j != 6) {
                        dataBase[j].dataVar.remove();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    dataBase[6].dataVar.append("text")
        .attr("x", width + 145)
        .attr("y", 9 + 25 * 6)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text(dataBase[6].dataName);



    dataBase[7].dataVar = svg.append("g")
        .attr("id", ("data " + (1 + 7)));

    // Add the valueline path.
    dataBase[7].dataVar.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .style("stroke", dataBase[7].colorcode)
        .attr("d", dataBase[7].valueline(data));

    dataBase[7].dataVar.selectAll("dot")    
        .data(data)         
    .enter().append("circle")                           
        .attr("r", 4.0)      
        .style("fill", dataBase[7].colorcode)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d["Date"]); })       
        .attr("cy", function(d) { 
            return y(d[dataBase[7].columnline]); 
        })     
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
            div.transition()        
                .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .9);      
            div .html(formatTime(d["Date"]) + "<br/>" + 
            "Quantity: " + d[dataBase[7].columnline])  
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
            })                  
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
            div.transition()        
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0);   
        });

    dataBase[7].dataVar.append("rect")
        .attr("x", width + 150)
        .attr("y", 25 * 7)
        .attr("width", 18)
        .attr("height", 18)
        .style("fill", dataBase[7].colorcode)
        .on("click", function(d) {
            if (singleData) {
                singleData = false;
                svg.selectAll("g").remove();
                d3.csv("data.csv", drawGraph);
            }
            else {
                singleData = true;
                for (j = 0; j < dataBase.length; j++) {
                    if (j != 7) {
                        dataBase[j].dataVar.remove();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    dataBase[7].dataVar.append("text")
        .attr("x", width + 145)
        .attr("y", 9 + 25 * 7)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text(dataBase[7].dataName);



    dataBase[8].dataVar = svg.append("g")
        .attr("id", ("data " + (1 + 8)));

    // Add the valueline path.
    dataBase[8].dataVar.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .style("stroke", dataBase[8].colorcode)
        .attr("d", dataBase[8].valueline(data));

    dataBase[8].dataVar.selectAll("dot")    
        .data(data)         
    .enter().append("circle")                           
        .attr("r", 4.0)      
        .style("fill", dataBase[8].colorcode)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d["Date"]); })       
        .attr("cy", function(d) { 
            return y(d[dataBase[8].columnline]); 
        })     
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
            div.transition()        
                .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .9);      
            div .html(formatTime(d["Date"]) + "<br/>" + 
            "Quantity: " + d[dataBase[8].columnline])  
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
            })                  
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
            div.transition()        
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0);   
        });

    dataBase[8].dataVar.append("rect")
        .attr("x", width + 150)
        .attr("y", 25 * 8)
        .attr("width", 18)
        .attr("height", 18)
        .style("fill", dataBase[8].colorcode)
        .on("click", function(d) {
            if (singleData) {
                singleData = false;
                svg.selectAll("g").remove();
                d3.csv("data.csv", drawGraph);
            }
            else {
                singleData = true;
                for (j = 0; j < dataBase.length; j++) {
                    if (j != 8) {
                        dataBase[j].dataVar.remove();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    dataBase[8].dataVar.append("text")
        .attr("x", width + 145)
        .attr("y", 9 + 25 * 8)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text(dataBase[8].dataName);


    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")     
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")     
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

}

d3.csv("data.csv", drawGraph);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The contents of the csv file which the code above displays in the form of a graph is:

```
Date,First,Second,Third,Fourth,Fifth,Sixth,Seventh,Eighth,Ninth
5/10/2013,0,15,30,45,60,75,90,105,120
5/13/2013,5,20,35,50,65,80,95,110,125
5/14/2013,10,25,40,55,70,85,100,115,130
5/15/2013,15,30,45,60,75,90,105,120,135
5/16/2013,20,35,50,65,80,95,110,125,140
5/17/2013,25,40,55,70,85,100,115,130,145
5/20/2013,30,45,60,75,90,105,120,135,150
5/21/2013,35,50,65,80,95,110,125,140,155
5/22/2013,40,55,70,85,100,115,130,145,160
5/23/2013,45,60,75,90,105,120,135,150,165
5/24/2013,50,65,80,95,110,125,140,155,170
5/28/2013,55,70,85,100,115,130,145,160,175
5/29/2013,60,75,90,105,120,135,150,165,180
5/30/2013,65,80,95,110,125,140,155,170,185
5/31/2013,70,85,100,115,130,145,160,175,190
6/3/2013,75,90,105,120,135,150,165,180,195
6/4/2013,80,95,110,125,140,155,170,185,200
6/5/2013,85,100,115,130,145,160,175,190,205
6/6/2013,90,105,120,135,150,165,180,195,210
6/7/2013,95,110,125,140,155,170,185,200,215
6/10/2013,100,115,130,145,160,175,190,205,220
6/12/2013,105,120,135,150,165,180,195,210,225
6/13/2013,110,125,140,155,170,185,200,215,230
6/17/2013,115,130,145,160,175,190,205,220,235
6/18/2013,120,135,150,165,180,195,210,225,240
6/19/2013,125,140,155,170,185,200,215,230,245
6/20/2013,130,145,160,175,190,205,220,235,250
6/21/2013,135,150,165,180,195,210,225,240,255
6/24/2013,140,155,170,185,200,215,230,245,260
6/25/2013,145,160,175,190,205,220,235,250,265
6/26/2013,150,165,180,195,210,225,240,255,270
6/27/2013,155,170,185,200,215,230,245,260,275
6/28/2013,160,175,190,205,220,235,250,265,280
7/1/2013,165,180,195,210,225,240,255,270,285
7/2/2013,170,185,200,215,230,245,260,275,290
7/3/2013,175,190,205,220,235,250,265,280,295
7/5/2013,180,195,210,225,240,255,270,285,300
7/8/2013,185,200,215,230,245,260,275,290,305
7/9/2013,190,205,220,235,250,265,280,295,310
7/10/2013,195,210,225,240,255,270,285,300,315
7/11/2013,200,215,230,245,260,275,290,305,320
7/12/2013,205,220,235,250,265,280,295,310,325
```

There are many lines in which I could save a lot of space and make it so editing the code would be a lot easier if I used a loop to replace those lines. The problem is, when I create certain loops, the code will crash because I have problems with the scoping.

Here's a part of the javascript code that I am trying to replace with a loop.

```
dataBase[0].valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d["Date"]); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d[dataBase[0].columnline]); });

dataBase[1].valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d["Date"]); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d[dataBase[1].columnline]); });

dataBase[2].valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d["Date"]); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d[dataBase[2].columnline]); });

dataBase[3].valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d["Date"]); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d[dataBase[3].columnline]); });

dataBase[4].valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d["Date"]); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d[dataBase[4].columnline]); });
```

// And so on...

Here is a code that I have used to try to get around the scoping trouble:

```
function xFunc(d) {
    return function (d) { return x(d["Date"]) };
}

function yFunc(d, i) {
    return function (d) { return y(d[dataBase[i].columnline]) };
}

for (var i = 0; i < dataBase.length; i++) {

    dataBase[i].valueline = d3.svg.line()
        .x(xFunc(d))
        .y(yFunc(d, i));

}
```

But when I use that code to replace the valueline codes, the graph ends up not showing at all in the html file. So far, the binding methods have not worked. Does anyone know a way I can successfully create a loop that can do the same thing as using multiple lines of code?

Comment: The block that shows only the valuelines, I didn't go all the way because of the limit in the number of characters I can use.

Comment: Please reduce the amount of code posted to ONLY the portion relevant to illustrate your question.  Are hundreds of lines of code needed to illustrate your question?

Comment: I tried including only the portion in a previous question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24517642/can-someone-tell-me-how-to-replace-the-following-javascript-code-with-a-loop?noredirect=1#comment37960981_24517642 but I got a few comments stating that they needed to see the surrounding code.

Comment: Also, there is another part in which only the portion is shown, but that portion is smaller than what I intended because of the 30k limit.

Comment: I answered by I saw that the code used in the other question is actually different from what you posted here. Someone asked you to clarify the statement "But that also resulted in an error as well.", but you did not do that. At this point it's impossible to help you since we don't even know which one is the code you are using or which error do you get. Also, if someone asks to provide more info, you should **edit** the question, not create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

`d` is passed by D3, not by you. At the moment you call `xFunc` and `yFunc`, `d` does not exist and you probably get a `ReferenceError`. Remove it from the signature of the functions.

Also, since `xFunc` does not depend on the loop variable, there is no need to have it return a function in every iteration.

```
function xFunc(d) {
    return x(d["Date"]) };
}

function yFunc(i) {
    return function (d) { return y(d[dataBase[i].columnline]) };
}

for (var i = 0; i < dataBase.length; i++) {

    dataBase[i].valueline = d3.svg.line()
        .x(xFunc)
        .y(yFunc(i));
}
```

---

[Learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820)